# aws-amplify Authentication...how to access tokens on successful Auth.signIn?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-amplify

I'm trying to figure out how to access the accessToken, refreshToken, and idToken that I receive back from aws-amplify using the Auth library.

example in docs: https://aws.github.io/aws-amplify/media/authentication_guide.html

example of my usage:

`const user = await Auth.signIn(email, password);`

`user` has a bunch of properties that are inaccessible including everything I need. In the docs, it's unclear how to get to these properties because the examples all log the result. Any ideas?

Comment: I posted this question in the aws-amplify repo and a collaborator replied: Auth.currentSession().accessToken.jwtToken

Answer (score 56):

```js
Auth.currentSession().then(res=>{
  let accessToken = res.getAccessToken()
  let jwt = accessToken.getJwtToken()
      
  //You can print them to see the full objects
  console.log(`myAccessToken: ${JSON.stringify(accessToken)}`)
  console.log(`myJwt: ${jwt}`)
})
```

Comment: This worked for me! You can also add ```console.log(`sub: ${JSON.stringify(accessToken.payload.sub)}`)``` if you are using Amplify and AWS and want the sub (ID).

Comment: Shouldn't there be an AWAIT in front?

Answer (score 22):

`Auth.currentSession()` will return a *CognitoUserSession* containing `accessToken`, `idToken`, and `refreshToken`.

The *CognitoUserSession* is actually the following: `CognitoUserSession {idToken: CognitoIdToken, refreshToken: CognitoRefreshToken, accessToken: CognitoAccessToken, clockDrift: 0}`

Accessing pairs within that object can be achieved through straightforward dot notation at this point.

---

**Example**: Retrieve the accessToken and log to console

```js
Auth.currentSession().then(data => console.log(data.accessToken));
```

The result will be a *CognitoAccessToken* in the form `CognitoAccessToken { jwtToken: '', payload: ''}`

If you just want the `jwtToken` within the *CognitoAccessToken*, it's just dot notation all the way down (with log to console example):

```js
Auth.currentSession().then(data => console.log(data.accessToken.jwtToken));
```

---

**Note**: This method also refreshes the current session if needed ([reference](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#retrieve-current-session)).

Comment: `This method also refreshes the current session if needed`
Thanks for that

Comment: But in my case it's not refreshing the accessToken with new one if current is expired.

Comment: `Auth.currentSession()` can only be done from the client right? You cannot do that in the server if you configure Amplify there

Answer (score 4):

I believe you can do

```
Auth.currentCredentials(credentials => {
  const tokens = Auth.essentialCredentials(credentials);
})
```

where [essentialCredentials](https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/blob/f1edbdef3f4c7fe7511d016e3ce8456601d1a306/packages/aws-amplify/src/Auth/Auth.ts#L719-L727) will return all of the tokens

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Angular 9, getting JWT token from current session :

```
import Auth from '@aws-amplify/auth';

Auth.currentSession().then(data => console.log("JWT", data.getAccessToken().getJwtToken()));
```

Answer (score 1):

For those in search of the [AWSCredentials](https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/api/classes/awscredentials.html):

```
const checkCognitoUserSession = async () => {
  const getAwsCredentials = await Auth.currentCredentials();
  const awsCredentials = await Auth.essentialCredentials(getAwsCredentials);

  // accessKeyId, secretAccessKey, sessionToken post login
  return { awsCredentials };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Retrieve current session using aws-amplify

Auth.currentSession() returns a CognitoUserSession object which contains JWT accessToken, idToken, and refreshToken.

```
Auth.currentSession()
.then((data) => console.log(data))
.catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

aws-amplify Docs [currentSession](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/manageusers/q/platform/js/#retrieve-current-session)